# I got exception with dateFormatter with "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I got exception when using the following code :

```
var expDate : NSDate = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
expDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Sun Apr 19 10:33:18 GST 2009")
```

I've tried e and E instead of EEE , Z and ZZZ instead of z
but didn't work
does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: Since `NSTimeZone` recognizes `GST` and since IANA includes it in their official list, I would consider this to be a bug in the framework. `GST` is an official shorthand for the `Asia/Dubai` time zone.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "GST" isn't a supported abbreviation. See https://gist.github.com/norio-nomura/d4d2475d62e446f796d8 for want of an official source.

Comment: But `NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GST")` returns a valid time zone object.

Comment: @MartinR You're right , however when I changed into "GMT" it worked!

Comment: while "GST" is a valid abbreviation for `NSTimeZone`, `NSDateFormatter` "z" specifier requires "GMT+4".